# Python put previous written line into variable

Tags: python

I am using a module that when it outputs an error it just prints that error and continues the script, I would like to put that error into a variable, however because of this behavour I cant just do except Exception as e, so I'm looking for a way to put the previously printed line into a variable
note: I tried looking in the module for where it prints this, but couldnt find it

Comment: Some Code, Please!

Comment: What is this module that you're using? If it really just swallows all exceptions as you say then I'm inclined to say it's garbage and you should find something else for the task.

Comment: link to the module + code snippet reproducing the issue, please. The proper solution is definitly not to "put the previously printed line into a variable" anyway, that's not how things work.

Comment: you can use `logging` to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it ain't pretty, but you could (hoping the write does not do anything funny) try to hijack `sys.stdout.write()` (or `stderr`, depending on where you script writes to).

This could be one way to do so, as ugly as it may be:

```
import sys
class Wrap:
     def __init__(self):
         self.last_line = None
         self._next_line = ''
     def write(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
         sys.__stdout__.write(text, *args, **kwargs)
         self._next_line += text
         try:
             self.last_line = self._next_line.split('\n')[-2]
             self.next_line = self._next_line.split('\n')[-1]
         except IndexError:
             # We did not have \n yet and _next_line did not split
             # into at least two items
             pass


save_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Wrap()
print('xxx\nzzz')  # This was that function you wanted to call
last_line = sys.stdout.last_line
sys.stdout = save_stdout

print(last_line)
```

This will give you `zzz` as output. I.e. last line printed (w/o newline (re)added) while `sys.stdout` was our wrapper.

You can of course just write a function wrapper and use that to formalize the hack a bit.